# HTML display 2 items in one row with a fixed width without break

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My question may be simple but I don't get it working. I want to have 2 inputs in one row. So lets say we place it inside a div and give this div a width of 20%. Now the two inputs will calculate the size and will make each 50%. The problem is that the div will set a break. If I place them inside a span, which will not insert a break, then I can't give it a width.

[image]

I want the inputs after "Plz/Ort" to have an overall size of 20%.

```
<label class="Label" for="City">Plz/ Ort*</label>
<span style="margin-left: 9.7%; width: 20%; display: flex-box; white-space:nowrap;">
  <input ng-model="user.plz" type="number" id="City"> -
  <input ng-model="user.city" type="text" id="City">
</span>
```

If I change it to this then it is still the same.

```
<label class="Label" for="City">Plz/ Ort*</label>
<div style="margin-left: 9.7%; width: 20%; display: inline-block; white-space:nowrap;">
  <input ng-model="user.plz" type="number" id="City"> -
  <input ng-model="user.city" type="text" id="City">
</div>
```

With span I can't give them a width.

Comment: You also have invalid HTML - can't have 2 elements with the same `ID` that should either be a class or you should have different `id`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue your attempt with flexbox:

**HTML**

```
<label class="Label" for="City">Plz/ Ort*</label>
<span>
    <input ng-model="user.plz" type="number" id="City">
    <span>-</span>
    <input ng-model="user.city" type="text" id="City">
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
label + span {
   margin-left: 9.7%;
   width: 20%;
   display: inline-flex; /* adjusted */
   white-space: nowrap;
 }

input { flex: 0 0 45%; } /* width adjusted for dash character */
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rc1rbg2k/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the display to inline-block
Use div instead of span

```
<label class="Label" for="City">Plz/ Ort*</label>
    <div style="margin-left: 9.7%; width: 20%; display: inline-block; white-space:nowrap;">
      <input ng-model="user.plz" type="number" id="City"> -
      <input ng-model="user.city" type="text" id="City">
    </div>
```

Comment: makes sense to me, since `<div>` is a block and `<span>` is inline

Comment: I tried it, but I get the same result. So the problem is that I can't give the div a width.

Comment: sure, I just meant that inline-block seems to be the css box model the OP is going for.  Yeah, making a div inline - or a span a block - kind of breaks the semantic meaning of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<div>` instead of span. You can set the width of `<div>` elements.